# MPMoviePlayerViewController Stops Playing

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to present a MoviePlayer on a NavigationController stack but it often randomly stops after a few seconds

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerViewController *player;
```

implementation:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL: [self preSignedURL:key]];
self.player = moviePlayer;
[[self navController]presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.player];
```

Have tried several alternatives including creating a UIViewController and displaying on its view before adding to the nav controller but the same result.

Comment: Can you share how you create an url? As far as I know *[NSURL fileURLWithPath:..]* should be used for local files.

Comment: It's done using S3GetPreSignedURLRequest   (Amazon S3). The movie does play sometimes, but generally cuts out after a few seconds

Comment: I believe you forgot to add source type. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

As it is stream you should change source type to streaming

```
moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
```

Comment: Interestingly I now get the error: An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer. but some progress I suppose

Comment: ok got it going but still cutting out after a few seconds of play